# How to add limit clause using content provider

Tags: android, uri, limit, android-contentprovider

Is there a way to limit the number of rows returned from content provider?
I found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3479424/1246000), however, it did not work for me.  All of the rows are still being returned.

```
Uri uri = Playlists.createIdUri(playlistId); //generates URI
uri = uri.buildUpon().appendQueryParameter("limit", "3").build();     
Cursor cursor = activity.managedQuery(playlistUri, null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: Just an idea. But you can try to put the limit clause as the last parameter. Like so activity.managedQuery(playlistUri, null, null, null, "limit 3") ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I have had this issue and had to break my head till I finally figured it out, or rather got a whay that worked for me. Try the following

```
Cursor cursor = activity.managedQuery(playlistUri, null, null, null, " ASC "+" LIMIT 2");
```

The last parameter is for sortOrder. I provided the sort order and also appended the LIMIT to it. Make sure you give the spaces properly. I had to check the query that was being formed and this seemed to work.

Comment: Will "ASC LIMIT 2" not work?

Comment: Won't work if last 2 rows in asc order are required. it will fetch the first two rows

Comment: For a better approach see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24055457/313113)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, ContentResolver can't query having limit argument. Inside your ContentProvider, your MySQLQueryBuilder can query adding the additional limit parameter.

Following the agenda, we can add an additional URI rule inside ContentProvider.

```
static final int ELEMENTS_LIMIT = 5;
public static final UriMatcher uriMatcher;

static {
uriMatcher = new UriMatcher( UriMatcher.NO_MATCH );
........
uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "elements/limit/#", ELEMENTS_LIMIT);
}
```

Then in your query method

```
String limit = null; //default....
    switch( uriMatcher.match(uri)){
       .......
                case ELEMENTS_LIMIT:
                    limit = uri.getPathSegments().get(2);
                break;
       ......

            }

return mySQLBuilder.query( db, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder, limit );
```

Querying ContentProvider from Activity.

```
 uri = Uri.parse("content://" + ContentProvider.AUTHORITY + "/elements/limit/" + 1 );

//In My case I want to sort and get the greatest value in an X column. So having the column sorted and limiting to 1 works.
    Cursor query = resolver.query(uri,
                        new String[]{YOUR_COLUMNS},
                        null,
                        null,
                        (X_COLUMN + " desc") );
```

Answer (score 2):

A content provider should on general principle pay attention to a limit parameter.
Unfortunately, it is not universally implemented.

For instance, when writing a content provider to handle SearchManager queries:

```
String limit = uri.getQueryParameter(SearchManager.SUGGEST_PARAMETER_LIMIT);
```

Where it isn't implemented you can only fall back on the ugly option of gluing a limit on the sort clause.