# CalendarContract query with limit

Tags: android, calendarcontract

How can I query CalendcarContract.Instances with a LIMIT clause?

I would like to query starting with a particular start date for a LIMIT of "n" rows.

What I've tried is:

```
final Uri uri = Uri.parse(CalendarContract.Instances.CONTENT_URI + "/" + 
                          Long.toString(startDate) + "/" + 
                          Long.MAX_VALUE);

final String sortOrder = Instances.BEGIN;

String selection = " limit " + rows;

Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query (
  uri,
  projection, 
  selection,
  null,
  sortOrder);
```

This generates an error, reported in the log file:

```
...while compiling: SELECT Instances._id...WHERE (begin<=? AND end>=? AND (limit 1)...
```

I believe the error is the "AND" before (limit 1).  The service is adding that, not me.  So, is there another URI I can use or another technique?

NB: I specifically want the Instances versions, which joins single events with recurring events.

Thanks.

Comment: The `ContentProvider` API does not support this. Any hacking-in-the-SQL solution like you are doing will be fragile, dependent as it is upon the specific implementation of the provider, which will vary by OS level and manufacturer.

Comment: Agreed.  Unfortunately I'll have to live with that risk or forego the functionality I need.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, never mind unless you have a better answer.

I realized this is a more general URI problem, not specifically related to CalendarContract.  In searching for other results, I found one suggestion to append LIMIT n to the sort clause, e.g.

```
final String sortOrder = Instances.BEGIN + " limit " + 10;
```

Credit to
[How to add limit clause using content provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898043/how-to-add-limit-clause-using-content-provider)