# Update Query In Content Provider

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I want to use Limit and Order By "abc"  DESC    in Query , i am not getting
solution

```
BuyActivity.this
            .getContentResolver()
                          .update(LearnBirdContactClass.LearbirdTable.SUB_CAT_URI_CONTENT_URI,
                                    contentValuessubcat,
                                    LearnBirdContactClass.SubCategortyTableColumns.CAT_ID
                                            + " = ? AND "
                                            + LearnBirdContactClass.SubCategortyTableColumns.SUB_CAT_ID
                                            + " = ?", new String[] { catId, });
```

How to add limit and Order By in this

Thanks

Comment: "limit" and "order by"? in update??? what would it be for?

Comment: please refer this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898043/how-to-add-limit-clause-using-content-provider

Comment: i want to update  only first row of from where id is 5 so why needed limit and order from desc so why?

Comment: i'm not sure if android's sqlite db supports that, see https://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#enable_update_delete_limit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQLite library in Android has not enabled the UPDATE/DELETE LIMIT clause, so even if the content provider had an interface for such a limit (which it hasn't), it would not work.

You have no choice but to uniquely identify the row(s) you want to update.